# How to Redirect to another url after POST request to PARSE / GRAB data ? Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am sending a JSON post request to a URL with headers and para:

```
headers = {
    'channel':'mobiApp',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    'Content-Length': '939',
    'Cookie': 'xyzxcasd',
    'User-Agent': 'okhttp/3.8.0'
    }
url = 'https://api.xyz.com/account.jsp'
data = {'act':'login','class':'profile','prftcf':code1,'p':password1,'u':username1,'ver':'0.9.1'}
content = json.dumps(data)
print ("")
print (content)
print ("")
r = requests.post(url,headers=headers,data=content,allow_redirects=True)
z = r.text
```

(above is the request I am sending)

I am getting this as response:

```
{
  "s": 0,
  "err": "",
  "errCode": "",
  "status": "",
  "ccnt": 1,
  "em": "blueyes81382@yahoo.com",
  "pid": "2436999645",
  "bvUserToken": "ee936b7065353389878696fc7cc4d71a646174653d3230313730393137267573657269643d32343336393939363435" 
}
```

What I want to do is redirect after this post request (if `bvUSertoken` exists) to some URL, i.e.: `https://api.xyz.com/acount/summary`, and print the response.

Comment: What do you mean by redirect? Are you doing this from a web server like Django and need to redirect the browser to some specific url `https://api.xyz.com/acount/summary`? Or is it that you need to make another api request if `bvUserToken` is available?

Comment: i wanna do something like this https://hastebin.com/iwowakiwol.bash .

Comment: If you want to grab more information from some other url if `bvUserToken` exist you can simply do a `if` check on `bvUserToken` and make a request to your intended url, grab the response and proceed, with whatever you want to do with that data.

This is a very simple scenario of making a further request on the existence of `bvUserToken`. So what exactly are you having trouble with? I don't think you are having trouble with checking the value of `bvUserToken` or making a new request.

Comment: i tried it making a if statement and requests.get(wahteverulr,headers) and print response.text  but it showed me this {
  "s": 10,
  "err": "mobile_m_error_required_login"
}

Comment: The problem is not with redirect, the problem is with the authorization. You must not be sending the `cookie` along with the headers of your request. Look at line no: 111 of your hastebin link. There a cookie is set to be sent.

Comment: this is what i wrote : https://hastebin.com/emeweqituk.pl

Comment: yay i got the thing was i had to grab the repsonse header cookies and send them to the redirect url header :P thanks fam,

Comment: Glad your problem got solved. Just to remind you. Don't hardcode the values of the `Cookie` header. The value of the `cookie` header will change with time. So never hardcode things like `cookie` or `authorization`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay so i found a solution to this

### p['Set-cookie'] parse cookie from previous response header

```
cookies = (p['Set-Cookie'])

    headers1 = {
        'channel':'mobiApp',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        'Cookie' : cookies,
        'User-Agent': 'okhttp/3.8.0'
        }

url = 'your redirect url'
urlx = url
parsing = requests.get(urlx,headers=headers1)
```